# What System.Windows.Forms.Design Editors Exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

By searching quite a bit I found the following:

```
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

This allows the visual studio designer to open an editor to edit List properties.

I tried to find other pre-existing editors but failed...

Do you know any? where I can find a complete list?

Thank you

Comment: Just explore the [System.Windows.Forms.Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design) Namespace